# regular expression to find MD5 in text file

Tags: regex, md5

I have text file containing text data ,which contain various data like MD5 , ssh of file and other texts.

I want to read only MD5 from text file .
My Code:

```html
with open(outfile,'r') as ofile:
        contents = ofile.read()
        contents = contents.lower()
        data = ''
        md5s = re.findall('[0-9a-f\$]{32}',contents)
        outfile = path[:-3] + 'md5'
        uniquemd5s = []
        for md5 in md5s:
            if md5 not in uniquemd5s:
                uniquemd5s.append(md5)
        for md5 in uniquemd5s:
            data = data +md5+"\n"
        with open(outfile,'w') as fp:
            fp.write(data)
```

However the problem here is that , Expression returning valid MD5 as well as first 32 chars of ssh also. So how to restrict the expression to select only 32 chars long MD5.

Data in text file is like:

TLP: White For any inquiries, please contact intelreports@kaspersky.com12

2. PAExec_Move0.dat

MD5  972092CBE7791D27FC9FF6E9ACC12CC3

Figure 3. Carbanak digital signature

Trojanized sshd, ssh, ssh-add and the target of the libkeyutils.so.1 symbolic link.
•  98cdbf1e0d202f5948552cebaa9f0315b7a3731d  Linux/Ebury – Version 0.4.4 – sshd
•  4d12f98fd49e58e0635c6adce292cc56a31da2a2  Linux/Ebury – Version 0.4.4 – sshd

Comment: What does "an ssh of file" mean?

Comment: it is same like MD5, only difference is that MD5 iscombination of 32 alphanumaric(0-F) and ssh is 40 chars long.

Comment: What separates the data in the file?

Comment: Data is like this in txt file                                                                                     MD5  08F83D98B18D3DFF16C35A20E24ED49A

Figure 2. Carbanak digital signature

 

TLP: White For any inquiries, please contact intelreports@kaspersky.com12

2.  PAExec_Move0.dat 

MD5  972092CBE7791D27FC9FF6E9ACC12CC3                                                             Trojanized sshd, ssh, ssh-add and the target of the libkeyutils.so.1 symbolic link.
•  98cdbf1e0d202f5948552cebaa9f0315b7a3731d  Linux/Ebury – Version 0.4.4 – sshd

Comment: Please add it to your question so we can see the formatting.

Comment: Does it actually say MD5 before each one?

Comment: No, there could be mentioned or not , no fixed criteria

Comment: Go with Lorenz's answer.

Comment: It is not returning anything , not even valid mD5s

Comment: First I am converting pdf into textfile using PDfMiner, then parsing text file to saperate MD5s to another file. https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/CORP_KNOWLEDGEBASE/67000/KB67957/en_US/Combating%20Threats%20-%20Operation%20Aurora.pdf     this is the path where you will get PDF

Answer (score 1):

Add the word separator to the regex :

```
md5s = re.findall('\b[0-9a-fA-F]{32}\b',contents)
```

This will avoid finding the SHA hash.

Note: SSH is not a hash. It stands for 'secure shell' and allows remote terminal sessions.

Comment: It is not returning anything , not even valid MD5

Comment: Sorry for the typos. The auto correct was joking with me. Also, I don't recognize the language you use. I guess `findall` is case sensitive. Thus I added `A-F` in caps.

Comment: I suspect he's using Python by the looks of it. Somehow your SSH has become SHA somehow too, which is no doubt what he meant and is a hash.